# Filter Invoke-RestMethod results

Tags: powershell, powershell-2.0

I am pulling some details about providers back from my application via a GET `Invoke-RestMethod`.
Currently it is returning all the details about providers. I want to only return the code of providers where the active status is set to True.

```
$acctname = 'user1'
$password = 'secret'

$params = @{uri = 'http://localhost:8080/tryout/settings/provider/providerDetails';
                   Method = 'Get';
                   Headers = @{Authorization = 'Basic ' + [Convert]::ToBase64String([Text.Encoding]::ASCII.GetBytes("$($acctname):$($password)"))
           } #end headers hash table
   } #end $params hash table


# This gets all the basic info ok
$var = invoke-restmethod @params

#show the values in the console
echo $var
```

It currently returns all these details. All I need is just the code if active-true.

```
id            : 90
name          : Test 1
active        : True
code          : NOT_STATED
system        : False
objectVersion : 2

id            : 91
name          : Test 2
active        : True
code          : MAIN
system        : False
objectVersion : 3

id            : 20372
name          : Test 3
active        : True
code          : NOT_STATED
system        : True
objectVersion : 2

id            : 30382
name          : Test 4
active        : True
code          : OP
system        : False
objectVersion : 1
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Just *pipe* `$var` to the `Where-Object` cmdlet and filter them:

```
$var | Where-Object active -eq 'True'
```

Comment: pretty sure you need `"` around `True`

Comment: @4c74356b41 pretty sure you don't ;-)

Comment: @4c74356b41 Just try it: `[PSCustomObject]@{name = "True"}, [PSCustomObject]@{name = "False"} | Where-Object name -eq True`

Comment: so that's not unique to `irm`, rather to `PSCustomObjects`... who knew, thanks! Also, there is a merit to using `.where()` instead of piping ;) ps. irm = invoke-restmethod

Comment: @4c74356b41 What does irm stand for?

Comment: `irm` is the alias for `Invoke-RestMethod`

Comment: If the string contains spaces; quotes are required. For consistency; I would advocate their usage all the time `:-)`

Comment: @gvee Yes, I agree with you and will change my answer.

Comment: Hi All, thanks for the pointers now working correctly (the figures that I am getting back now look good anyway). Gone with the double quotes just to be safe.

Comment: This solution works for me. But if I skip the $var and pipe the output directly to Where-Object it doesn't?

Comment: For me, it only works if I do `$var | Where-Object enabled -eq $true` - note that I am using an `enabled` property, not `active`